# Google script to find if a Cell is blank - isBlank function doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

Here is my code. I'm trying to execute the code only if the cell is not blank. As we do not have a inbuilt function for isBlank i though of using it to fill the empty cell with predefined value. But it do

```gs
for (var i = 2, k = 2, j = 2, s = 2; i<lastrow && k>0; s++){
   var range = sheet.getRange(i,1);
   var company = range.getValue();
   var range = sheet.getRange(i,2);
   var description = range.getValue();
   var range = sheet.getRange(i,3);
   var priority = range.getValue();
      var range = sheet.getRange(i,4);
   var urgency = range.getValue();
      var range = sheet.getRange(i,5);
   var impact = range.getValue();
      var range = sheet.getRange(i,6);
   var requester = range.getValue();
      var range = sheet.getRange(i,7);
   var status = range.getValue();
      var range = sheet.getRange(i,8);
   var subject = range.getValue();
   var pay="{\"helpdesk_ticket\":{ \"description\":\""+description+"\", \"subject\":\""+subject+"\",\"email\":\""+requester+"\",\"priority\":\""+priority+"\",\"status\":\""+status+"\",\"impact\":\""+impact+"\", \"urgency\":\""+urgency+"\"   }}";
   if(description.isBlank()){
   var url="https://"+purl+"/helpdesk/tickets.json"; 
   var options = {
                 "payload": pay,
                 "method": "POST",
                 "muteHttpExceptions": true,
```

Error message:
[image: see error screenshot]

Comment: You say that there is no function `isBlank()`. However you are still trying to call it here: `if(description.isBlank())`.

Comment: It is a inbuild function in google

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isBlank()` is a method of the class `Range`. However you are trying to call it on `description`, which is not an object of the class `Range`, but one of `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, or `String` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Answer (score 2):

Because you get a value, its not a cell obj anymore, so its a string, and to check if string is 0 we use function length so in your case it should be like

```
...
if(description.length > 0)
...
```